# "gonna/going to have to" vs "have to"

Tags: meaning, phrases

Is there a difference between "gonna have to" and just "have to"? For instance, in the following two sentences:

> You’re gonna have to be completely honest.

and

> You have to be completely honest.

Comment: Your phrases don't seem to be grammatical regarding "to be completely let me" so I can't get the meaning. However “gonna have to” is slang for “going to have to”.

Comment: I’ve edited to focus on the question in the title, which I think is an interesting one at its core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Ya gonna hafta" is a sort of [African American Vernacular English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_American_Vernacular_English)--but even so, it's not the kind of thing *anyone* would usually say.  You'll only find that in song lyrics...or when someone is really trying to be over-the-top in a *"telling you from the soul"* way.  They want to let you know the hard truth about some tough thing you must do--for reasons of moral obligation or fundamental necessity.

Basically, avoid using "gonna have to" unless you have a grasp of the subtleties; it's slang.

> You have to be completely let me.

That makes no sense.  On the other hand, these sentences make sense:

- You have to be completely honest.
- You have to let me take care of it.
- You have to completely let go.
- You have to be completely calm.
- You have to be completely willing to let me take care of it.

When you say someone "has to be X", then X must be a "state of being".  "let me" is not a state of being.  "willing to let me take care of it" is.

Comment: I'm not sure why you say it's AAVE slang.  Suppose your friend says, "Hey listen to this new album I bought." And you then say, "Wow! That's really good, I'm gonna have to get that too."

Comment: @Jim I was referring specifically to when it is *"gonna hafta"*.  I don't know any appearance of "gonna" outside of song lyrics along with constructs like "gonna git", it's Southern at the least.  But I hear it most often by blues or otherwise affiliated artists.  Either way, if people you know actually say "I'm gonna have to get that too" then people you know talk differently than people I know.